# Make import module return a variable

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I would like to make an imported module behave like an object, ie. an dictionary.

E.g.

```
import module
print(module['key'])
```

and in `module.py`

```
return {'key':'access'}
```

This is very easy for `Class` by inheriting from `dict`, but how do I do this on a module level?

In particular I want to dynamically built the dictionary in `module` and return it when `module` is imported.

I know that there are other solutions such as defining the `dict` as a `var` in the `module` workspace and accessing it via `module.var`, but I am interested if something like this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you point out, you can do this with a class, but not with a module, as modules are not subscriptable.Now I'm not going to ask *why* you want to do this with an `import`, but it can be done.

What you do is create a class that does what you want, and then have the module replace itself with the class when imported. This is of course a 'bit of a hack' (tm). Here I'm using UserDict as it gives easy access to the dict via the class attr `data`, but you could do anything you like in this class:

```
# module.py

from collections import UserDict
import sys
import types

class ModuleDict(types.ModuleType, UserDict):
    data = {'key': 'access}

sys.modules[__name__] = ModuleDict(__name__)
```

Then you can import the module and use it as desired:

```
# code.py

import module
print(module['key']
# access
```